# NSOutlineView view-based "SourceList" display "regular"

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, nsoutlineview

I have `NSOutlineView` view-based `SourceList`  but display `regular`

I do not know what

**config**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

My full code project

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ow7y2v0pqw8ebv7/sideCompte.zip?dl=0

Comment: What is the color of a selected row? Is "Reduce transparency" in System Prefs switched on?

Comment: System Preferences / Accessibility / Reduce transparency is off and the color of a selected row is blue

Comment: does anyone have an idea? is it a bug on the part of apple it seems to me that yes

Comment: What happens if you change Highlight to Regular? Does it look the same? I tried your project and it looks ok to me.

Comment: it's always with triangles only the background that changes if I put regular I do not see the way around the bug. it's incomprehensible

Comment: How should it look? Like iTunes?

Comment: yes if you want, like a source list with a button hide / show [link] (https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/windows-and-views/sidebars/) or [link] (https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList)

Comment: What is the issue? Your project looks the same as iTunes and PXSourceList. SourceList is inherited from `NSTableView` and changes the colors.

Comment: the issue : there is no **hide / show** button like on iTunes

Comment: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineviewdelegate/1528482-outlineview) That's it I found the solution, we must add outlineView (_: isGroupItem :) true to indicate a particular row should have the "group row" style drawn for that row, otherwise false. and now I have the hide / show button like on iTunes Thank you very much